# Querying encrypted data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, certificate, sql-server-2014

For a specific requirement, I am to encrypt all personal data in a database.
I am doing so with a certificate, which I imported into SQL Server, so far so good.

Surely enough, I can do

```
DECLARE @Passwd nvarchar(128) = 'CertPassword'
SELECT Email as EmailEncrypted,
    CAST
    (
        DECRYPTBYCERT
        (
            CERT_ID('Cert'),
            Email,
            @Passwd
        ) AS varchar(128)
    ) AS EmailDecrypted
```

And it will show me the actual data.

**But what if I want to query based on a specific email?**

I have read somewhere that one approach is creating an additional column with the hash of the encrypted bytes and query on that column; it sounds ok, but not ideal.

**Is there any other reliable way of querying encrypted data?**

Comment: Are you able to use SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Latest I can use is 2014